# Frameworks for network protocol fuzzing?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, fuzzing

Can anyone recommend any programmer-friendly (i.e. extensible) frameworks or systems for performing network level packet [fuzzing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing)?

I'm looking for such a system where I can program in additional packet formats and various ways of breaking those packets in a protocol-dependent manner.

I know how to Google.  I'm looking for specific recommendations :)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [American Fuzzy Lop](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/) combined with [Preeny](https://github.com/zardus/preeny). It's a fuzzer that is quite simple to use and employs genetic algorithms, which in this case means that it's going to detect which changes in input bits lead to new code paths and pay more attention to those.

Answer (score 4):

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) looks really programmer friendly.  It is written in Python.

You use the Python command interpreter as its command interpreter.  It has very nice documentation.  It looks easy to use and understand.

API looks decent; written in a "pythonic" style.  It looks very complete and it is under active development.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the [Sulley fuzzing framework](http://code.google.com/p/sulley/). It's a python framework and good at its job.

If you want layer 2 protocol fuzzing check out the great work by the people at ernw.de:

http://www.ernw.de/download/l2sulley_04-15-08.tar.bz2

http://www.ernw.de/download/l2_fuzzing_shmoo08.pdf

What protocols in particular are you interested in fuzzing?

UPDATE: As you are targeting DNS you should check out the [PROTOS test suite](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/ouspg/protos/index.html), in particular their [DNS module](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/ouspg/protos/testing/c09/dns/index.html). This is a closed source Java package though, so you wont be able to use it like a framework, but you can always write a Sulley module to suite your specific needs if PROTOS isn't thorough enough.

Comment: While Sulley looks very complete (both for postmortem and fuzzing techniques), it's not good for testing: as far as I can see you can't capture (inside the fuzzing script) and base further actions on server responses. You have to post-process the packet captures to detect misbehaving server. Scapy is much better for that.

Answer (score 2):

I just Googled around. I have never used any of these.

- [The Art of Fuzzing](http://theartoffuzzing.com/joomla/index.php)
- [ProxyFuzz](http://theartoffuzzing.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=21&Itemid=40)
- [Sulley Fuzzing Framework](http://www.fuzzing.org/category/sulley/)
- [MalyFuzz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/malybuzz/)
- [JBroFuzz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbrofuzz)

Comment: I think some of these are kind of stale. TAoF has not been updated in several years

Answer (score 1):

I know fuzzled is really good as a framework, if you fancy with Perl : http://www.securiteam.com/tools/5FP0Q1PKUS.html

JborFuzz and most of other fuzzers won't do it since they are not designed as a framework, certainly not for network level.

Answer (score 1):

None of the proposed answers met my needs, so I wrote [my own fuzzing DNS server](https://github.com/raybellis/evldns) instead.

Comment: And not even a link to the github/bitbucket page?  :)

Comment: @BrianCain oh, all right then!  http://code.google.com/p/evldns/

Answer (score 1):

Here are my recommendations mainly because of the security groups which developed them has a great reputation.

- AutoFuzz ([Software](http://autofuzz.sourceforge.net/)) ([Paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/sergeyg/publications/autofuzz.pdf))
- SecFuzz ([Software](https://github.com/ptsankov/secfuzz)) ([Paper](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/basin/pubs/ast12.pdf))

**Scapy** is an amazing tool, but these frameworks use Scapy to do more.