# Network Protocol Testing

Tags: testing, protocols

I'm trying to master myself in network protocol testing (Protocols include : L2, L3 layer protocols in particular). Any suggestions on how to proceed , like links , pdf's etc would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is validating that parties participating in a session are correctly following the model of the protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking

It is more formal than fuzzing; as a result, it can provide stronger measures of "how correct" a given program is in respect to a given protocol, but it might be significantly more work to create appropriate models and model checking software. Fuzzers start returning bugs from the first second. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzing is an established technique to perform random, but directed testing. See [Frameworks for network protocol fuzzing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349791/frameworks-for-network-protocol-fuzzing)