# Best option to fuzz a C Network Program

Tags: c, fuzzy, fuzzing, fuzzer

I have a client/server simple program in C. I want to test the server running on different machine with random inputs. I have looked at 'Bunny-the-fuzzer' but from what I can understand It wont be much help when the target program/application is on remote machine.

Can someone recommend me any other available tools for testing such network programs ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frameworks for network protocol fuzzing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349791/frameworks-for-network-protocol-fuzzing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is still relevant there are numerous products that can fuzz network products, from open source tools like SPIKE and Peach to commercial fuzzers like beSTORM